# SUBSTRING_INDEX in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I wanted to extract a person's first name from a column containing sms texts. The texts generally begin with the word "Dear". eg. Dear Micheal Bay, your movie tickets...

While on mysql, I used   `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sms_text, " ", 2)," ", -1)`, but now i have to do the same thing on BIgQuery and I am unable to find a similar function.

**Sample Data:**

**Sms_text**

Dear, Micheal Jordan, your match tickets have been mailed to you.

Dear Virat Kohli, your flight will depart in 25 mins.

**Desired Output:**

Micheal

Virat

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please have a look at it now

Comment: `The texts generally begin with the word` - what you do if it is another word or two words, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

```
with t as (
select 'Dear, Micheal Jordan, your match tickets have been mailed to you.' as sms
union all
select 'Dear Virat Kohli, your flight will depart in 25 mins.' as sms
)
select split(sms,' ')[offset(1)] from t
```

this returns

```
Micheal

Virat
```